# Searching an Adjustable Distortion ' filter ' for video

Tags: effects, filter, distortion

Playing a 720p movie file  by VLC-mediaplayer (working normally with all other videofiles), gave a peculiar distortion, intermittently showing rather interesting visually pleasing patternings. Tried to find a video distortion filter by diverse terms in google but came up empty, only visual effect tips using adobe and the like that don't get to too interesting  results. Could anyone please let me know of a way to get an adjustable/modifiable video distortion mechanism or "filter"? Something that messes the videostream image up in several ways and in a fine-grained manner.

Comment: I  sampled some more worthwhile images to show what i mean: a bunch of jpegs meant to be quite  small in size, since it was made from a 720p video.                                                                            https://jmp.sh/N1wIWP4                link to uploaded jpegs

Comment: The jpegs lost lots of detail in transitioning through pinnacle rendering and mediaplayer single frame screen capture, yet still provide a vague argument that a willfull mind can understand.